# if condition of string and editText

Tags: android, if-statement

I'm newbie in android programming. And I'm being confused of the error in this line saying, "Incompatible operand types EditText and String"

the USERTYPE variable is a Spinner while the USER variable is an EditText

```
if((userType.getSelectedItem()=="Administrator")&(user=="1500110001"))
{
    login();  
}
```

Hope you could help the newbie here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: replace `&` with `&&` (first one is byte operation, second is AND boolean operation). Edit : is `user` is an EditText, you wanna call `user.getText().toString()`, and better check with `equals()` function, as `user.getText().toString().equals("1500110001")`

Comment: if((userType.getSelectedItem()=="Administrator")&&(user=="1500110001"))
{
    login();  
}

Answer (score 1):

Change `userType.getSelectedItem()` to `userType.getSelectedItem().getText()` and compare strings with `equals()`, and change `&` to `&&` (for reasons mentioned by @NicholasSimon), so like this

```
if(userType.getSelectedItem().getText().equals("Administrator") && (user.equals("1500110001"))
```